# Hf ionospheric channel model for large bandwidth

Tags: discrete-signals, fading-channel, multipath

I know some models like the Watterson model for HF ionospheric channels but those are limited to narrow band frequencies.

Are there some models to bandwidth like 12kHz up to 24 kHz?

Comment: If you want higher bandwidth, you'll need finer resolution of the channel coefficients (assuming you're going for a tapped delay-line model like Watterson), and that also brings reduced coherence time. So, the question really is, since every model is but a simplification of reality, what specifically do you need from that channel model?

Comment: Hello @MarcusMüller, do you konw the average number of taps for the watterson model in a normal environment ?

Comment: multiply the maximum expectable delay spread with your sampling rate, get number of taps

Comment: it results in 48 taps ... for 9.6 kbps and 5ms of maximum delay spread. That is huge !!
Is the number of taps, the same as the number of paths (in multipath scenario) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Watterson channel model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/examples/hf-ionospheric-channel-models.html#d118e11855), and it can be extended to any bandwidth